# Get python string from Tensor without the numpy function

Tags: tensorflow

I'm following the tutorial on https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow_docs/docs/site/en/tutorials/text/word_embeddings.ipynb

TextVectorization by defalut splits on whitespace but I want to implement custom split. I want to keep punctuations (which I have implemented in custom_standardization), and split between words and punctuations.

For instance, "fn(1,2)=1+2=3" needs to split to `["fn","(","1",",","2",")","=","1","+","2","=","3"]`.

```
def custom_split(input_data: tf.Tensor):
    assert input_data.dtype.name=='string'
    assert hasattr(input_data,'numpy') == False
    ???
    


vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    split=custom_split,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length)
```

I'm confident in such spliting given a standard Python string. However the input is tf.Tensor and following the aforementioned tutorial, input_data does not have numpy() function.

What's the proper way to do such spliting? Is it possible to retrieve Python string from string Tensor?

Comment: Have you tried using `tf.strings.split()`?

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I don't think `tf.strings.split()` supports custom logic.